# 32 Bit App Pool on Server 2012 with Exchange

Tags: iis-7, exchange-server, 32bit-64bit, application-pool, windows-server-2012

Ok so I have been keeping up with decompressing application pools and adding Pre Conditions to the applicationhost.config file.  I am now stumped on server 2012.

Symptom:
Application Pool keeps crashing, even log error kicks off 4 listener channel errors and then kills the the app pool.

Previous Fix for older version servers:
Backup IIS. I add Pre Condtions to exppw and (and in this case)cafe_exppw.  Additionally I add it to Kerbauth (In some cases the Pre Condtion was not needed.) Save. ResetIIS.  I then run Anilr's script (ref:http://forums.iis.net/t/1149768.aspx) below which does not work.  I am no programmer so I am not sure where to find an update version (if there is one) for 2012

```
%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set config -section:system.webServer/httpCompression /+[name='xpress',doStaticCompression='false',dll='%windir%\system32\inetsrv\suscomp.dll']
```

Thanks,

Jack

Comment: Left this out.... I am installing a 32 bit application, I can run under default or not, doesnt matter.  I will be using network service but can use a services account if need be.  Application pool is .net2, classic, ofcourse 32-bit enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Often a problem with the 64 bit rpcproxy.dll which is loaded by iis by default even when "enable 32 bit applications" is set to true.

Here's a link that explains

http://blogs.technet.com/b/sbs/archive/2011/04/07/how-to-run-a-32bit-web-application-on-sbs-2008.aspx

Could be the source of your problem

Wing

Comment: Thank you Wing, but I already reference that website.  I should have mentioned the RCP Proxy, which now comes with the Pre-Condition on SBS2k11 and most newer servers.  In some cases you also need to add it to exppw or even kerbauth; it varies depending on the server.  What I am looking for is Pre-Conditions I should be adding to Windows 2012 with Exchange installed.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who might be wondering how I got around this, just add `"bitness64" />` to kerbauth and anything exppw in GlobalModules in the web.config file. Reboot IIS, verify OWA still works and that should do it. You might see some kerbauth errors but I am yet to see any real issue stem from it.

For your information there is no need to decompress the app pool:

```
%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set config -section:system.webServer/httpCompression /-[name='xpress']
```